# Disable "Selected features only" in Proccessing Script

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I wrote a Progressing algorithm using Python. The tool clips  DEM by a select polygon in the vector layer. If there is no selection, the tool gives an error. As the script runs anyway for the selected object, I would like to disable the "Selected feature only" option if it is possible.

Any idea if it is possible?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Processing adds the `Selected features only` checkbox if you use a `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource` as input parameter, but it does not add the checkbox if you use a `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer`.

Compare:

[image]

Therefore, in your script, instead of using `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource` as input parameter type, use `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer`. Example:

```
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer(
        self.INPUT,
        self.tr('Input layer with QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer'),
        [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon]
    )
)
```

Now, in `processAlgorithm()` method, get the parameter in this way:

```
polygon_layer = self.parameterAsVectorLayer(
    parameters,
    self.INPUT,
    context
)
```

---

NOTE: *As you can see in the screenshot above, the `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource` has some advantages over `QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer`. So, if you use the latter, you won't get the handy options at the right hand side. Namely, iterate through features and advanced options buttons.*